# How can we get the count value or rows from input field in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

When I enter the number in input field it will reflect the text box that is how many numbers I enter in text box will show a text box in below.

[image]

If I enter the number as 2 means that in will show 2 text box.

[image]

I want that output in Jquery keyup so kindly provide a solution for that.

Code:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group padd-bottom">
       <label><h6 class="centerlized">Members : </h6></label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group padd-bottom">
        <input type="text" name="members" class="form-control eachmem" id="members" placeholder="Members">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add your code..

Comment: kindly check....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the jquery solution you are looking for.

Here we get the count value from and input field, and then run a `for...` loop to add input to the dom.

Each time when the input is changed, dom is cleared and then run a loop to add inputs.

```js
var $ = jQuery;
$('#input_count').on('keyup', function(){
  var count = $(this).val();
  var container = $('#form_container');  
  var el = `</br><input name="member[]" placeholder="element value" type="text"/>`;
  if(count){
    container.empty();
    for(var i = 0; i< count; i++){
      container.append(el);
    }  
  }else{
    container.empty();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="input_count" placeholder="element count" />

<div id="form_container">

</div>
```